# Sqlite query help needed?

Tags: android, sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE supportContacts
    (
     id integer primary key, 
     type varchar(20), 
     details varchar(30)
    );

INSERT INTO supportContacts
(id, type, details)
VALUES
(1, 'Email', 'admin@sqlfiddle.com');

INSERT INTO supportContacts
(id, type, details)
VALUES
(2, 'Twitter', '@sqlfiddle');


CREATE TABLE supportContacts2
    (
     type varchar(20), 
     details varchar(30)
    );

INSERT INTO supportContacts2
(type, details)
VALUES
('Email', 'admin@sqlfiddle.com');
```

Above are the two tables and  I want to get type from supportContacts and wants * in front of the type if that exists in supportContacts2.

Any suggestions ?

This is the smallest possible example I can take,actually I am working on a large query which have functionality like this.

here's the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657367/android-why-sqlite-union-behaves-abruptly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need all the results of `supportContacts`, you could use a LeftJoin and then a `CASE WHEN ... THEN ...`
This would look something like this (`s` is your `supportContacts` and s2 is `supportContacts2`)

```
SELECT s.id, s.details, CASE 
    WHEN s2.type IS NULL THEN '' 
    WHEN s2.type = '' THEN '' 
    ELSE '*' || s2.type 
    END AS type2
FROM supportContacts AS s LEFT JOIN supportContacts2 AS s2 ON s.type=s2.type
```

Haven't tested it, and there might be syntax errors, but that's the way you could manage it.

Comment: is `s2.type` empty? you could check by running the normal join without the `CASE WHEN` statement. I updated my answer to include the full query